# ¿Como sumar el total de dos registros en sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Espero me puedan apoyar,tengo los siguientes registros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que busco es restar el total de un boleto cuando este `strTipoVenta: EXCA` y tenga `strTipoDocumento F y NC`

Ejemplo:
El boleto **1392145269340** tiene 3414.1800 de NC y 4598.1800 de F, lo cual si lo restamos nos daría 1184.00 y que solo se vea el tipoDocumento F con el monto.

`1392145269340  F   EXCA    1184.00 113980055017104 2024-02-27`

Lo intenté hacer con un case pero no llegue al resultado que quería:

```
SELECT 
CI.dcmlNumeroBoleto, CI.strTipoDocumento, CI.strTipoVenta, CI.dcmlTotal,
CASE 
    WHEN CI.strTipoDocumento in ('F', 'NC') and CI.strTipoVenta = 'EXCA' THEN 
     CI.dcmlTotal - CI.dcmlTotal
    END as Total,
P.strNumeroCuentaMetodoPago, CI.dteFechaEmisionBoleto
FROM FEBoletos3_3..tblControlInterno AS CI
JOIN FEBoletos3_3..tblPagos AS P ON P.dcmlNumeroBoleto = CI.dcmlNumeroBoleto
WHERE P.strNumeroCuentaMetodoPago IN ('113980055017104') AND CI.intCodigoFacturable = 0 
AND CI.strTipoDocumento IN('F', 'NC') AND CI.BatchId in 
('af00be96809348b68c458a2818b05359','3cefc40df70247fe846801190ba44b20')
GROUP BY CI.dcmlNumeroBoleto, CI.strTipoDocumento, CI.strTipoVenta, CI.dcmlTotal, 
P.strNumeroCuentaMetodoPago, CI.dteFechaEmisionBoleto
ORDER BY CI.dteFechaEmisionBoleto DESC
```

Espero que me puedan guiar en mi error, se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: Si estan en dos registros distintos, tu primera mision, si decides aceptarla, es sacar una sola tabla con los registros emparejados por numero de boleto... una vez que logres eso... ya lo solucionaste...

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en que estás agrupando por `CI.strTipoVenta`, `CI.strTipoDocumento`, y `CI.dcmlTotal`: Esto causa que las 'F' y 'NC' (¿facturas y notas de crédito?) queden en una filas *cada una*, por lo cual la resta de tu `CASE WHEN` no va a restar las 'F' menos las 'NC'.

**Solución**: Una forma de obtener la resta, manteniendo las 'F' y 'NC' en filas separadas, consiste en hacer un `SUM() OVER` para las filas que tengan el mismo número de boleto y de cuenta sumen o resten sus `CI.dcmlTotal`. Abajo el ejemplo.

```sql
SELECT CI.dcmlNumeroBoleto, CI.strTipoDocumento, CI.strTipoVenta, CI.dcmlTotal,
SUM(IIF(CI.strTipoVenta = 'EXCA', CI.dcmlTotal, 0)
   *IIF(CI.strTipoDocumento='F', 1, -1)) 
  OVER(PARTITION BY CI.dcmlNumeroBoleto, P.strNumeroCuentaMetodoPago) as Total,
P.strNumeroCuentaMetodoPago, CI.dteFechaEmisionBoleto
FROM FEBoletos3_3..tblControlInterno AS CI
JOIN FEBoletos3_3..tblPagos AS P ON P.dcmlNumeroBoleto = CI.dcmlNumeroBoleto
WHERE P.strNumeroCuentaMetodoPago IN ('113980055017104') 
  AND CI.intCodigoFacturable = 0 
  AND CI.strTipoDocumento IN('F', 'NC') 
  AND CI.BatchId in ('af00be96809348b68c458a2818b05359', '3cefc40df70247fe846801190ba44b20')
GROUP BY CI.dcmlNumeroBoleto, CI.strTipoDocumento, CI.strTipoVenta, 
  CI.dcmlTotal,P.strNumeroCuentaMetodoPago, CI.dteFechaEmisionBoleto
ORDER BY CI.dteFechaEmisionBoleto DESC
```

**Otra forma**: también puedes:

- Quitar el campo `CI.strTipoDocumento` del `SELECT` y del `GROUP BY`;
- Quitar el `CI.dcmlTotal` del `GROUP BY`
- Eliminar el `OVER()` de la sumatoria.

De este modo, las 'F' y 'N' quedan combinadas en la misma fila. Prueba ambos métodos a ver cual da la visualización que buscas.

```sql
SELECT CI.dcmlNumeroBoleto, CI.strTipoVenta, CI.dcmlTotal,
SUM(IIF(CI.strTipoVenta = 'EXCA', CI.dcmlTotal, 0)
   *IIF(CI.strTipoDocumento='F', 1, -1))  as Total,
P.strNumeroCuentaMetodoPago, CI.dteFechaEmisionBoleto
FROM FEBoletos3_3..tblControlInterno AS CI
JOIN FEBoletos3_3..tblPagos AS P ON P.dcmlNumeroBoleto = CI.dcmlNumeroBoleto
WHERE P.strNumeroCuentaMetodoPago IN ('113980055017104') 
  AND CI.intCodigoFacturable = 0 
  AND CI.strTipoDocumento IN('F', 'NC') 
  AND CI.BatchId in ('af00be96809348b68c458a2818b05359', '3cefc40df70247fe846801190ba44b20')
GROUP BY CI.dcmlNumeroBoleto, CI.strTipoVenta, 
  P.strNumeroCuentaMetodoPago, CI.dteFechaEmisionBoleto
ORDER BY CI.dteFechaEmisionBoleto DESC
```

Un detalle más: ten cuidado con la velocidad de la consulta; esta tiene una agrupación (que tu agregaste), la sumatoria que yo sugerí, y la ordenación final. Una vez que tengas el resultado que buscas verifica también que sea eficiente.

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener lo que describes, necesitas:

- agrupar únicamente por `dcmlNumeroBoleto`
- sumar el campo `dcmlTotal`, aplicando el signo correspondiente según el `strTipoVenta` y `strTipoDocumento`

Por ejemplo:

```sql
select   ci.dcmlNumeroBoleto
       , sum(ci.dcmlTotal * 
             case
               when ci.strTipoVenta = 'EXCA' and ci.strTipoDocumento = 'NC' then -1
               else 1
             end
            ) as TotalBoleto
  from FEBoletos3_3..tblControlInterno ci
 where blah, blah
 group by ci.dcmlNumeroBoleto
```

Esto te dará el valor que buscas, en un resumen con un solo registro por cada número de boleto.